# Add background image/layout for single page?

Tags: plugins, css

I'm seeing that a lot of sites (moz.com,hubspot.com) are using a background image as a layout. How do I add a single background image easily onto WordPress? I also want to add the layout here: http://moz.com/blog onto my blog. How do I do this?

Comment: "Backgroound image as layout", ehm what?

Comment: I want to add a background layout image kind of like Moz.com.

Comment: I am not following what you mean by "background layout" term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that you want to add a background image for a specific page:

Create your CSS class for the background you want.

```
body.custombg {background: url("images/background.gif"); }
```

In the header, you can use something like this to check for a specific page.

```
<body <?php if(is_page(123)) echo 'class="custombg"' ?>>
```

See [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for more ideas of what you can do.

As for the layout of that site, you should contact them and find out if they are using a publicly available theme or if it is a custom design.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `body_class()`.

```
<body <?php body_class( is_page( 'about' ) ? 'special-class' : '' ); ?>>
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: Ehm... it's a `body` HTML tag? Search in your template, replace it with the answers code...